# How to run an update function only at the end of tweaking a slider

Tags: python, interface

Properties have a nifty little `update=function` [parameter](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_4/bpy.props.html?highlight=floatproperty#bpy.props.FloatProperty) which is run every time the property changes.

This is very useful, but when used on a slider in the UI, the update is run for every pixel (or something) the mouse is moved when dragging the slider.

Is it possible to only run the update once right at the end when the user releases their mouse button?

Comment: Pretty sure the only way this can be done is with a modal operator, and it would be more like: click, slide, confirm.